# jqgrid client side sorting desc/asc

Tags: jqgrid

I have seen the many many variations on this issue, and I've tried to use all the knowledge, but still no luck.

My dates are sorting old to new, and I want to sort them new to old.

Where you see desc, I've tried asc, but no change.

When I try the paging, it seems to trigger the reload, and the sort is right, from new to old.

Is the best solution to set a reload for 1 second, and clear interval?  Or do I have something else wrong?

I can't sort server side, it's just not an option.

```
    $("#transactionList").jqGrid({
       url: "/cc/transaction/show/"+accountId,
       datatype: "local",
       autowidth: true,
       height: 'auto',
       sortname: 'tran_date',
       sortorder: 'desc',
       sortable:true,
       loadonce:true,
       viewrecords: true,
       gridview: true,
       firstsortorder: 'desc',
       colNames:['Date','Asset Name','Description','Amount','Actions'],
       colModel:[
 {name:'tran_date',index:'tran_date',sorttype:'date',sortable:true,formatter:'date',firstsororder: 'desc',datefmt: 'M d,Y',formatoptions: {srcformat:'Y-m-d H:i:s',newformat:'M d,Y'}},
{name:'assname',index:'assname',sortable:true,resizable:false},
{name:'desccription',index:'desccription',sortable:true,resizable:false},
{name:'net_proc', index:'net_proc',align:'right',formatter:'currency',formatoptions{decimalSeparator:".", thousandsSeparator: ",", decimalPlaces: 2, prefix: "$", defaultValue:'0.00'}, sortable:true,resizable:false},   {name:'ID',index:'ID',formatter:actionsFormatter,width:130,align:"center",key:true,resizable:false}
      ],
      caption: "Completed Transactions",
      rowTotal: -1,
      rowNum: 1000,
      rowList: [10,20,30],
      pager: '#pager',
      onSelectRow: function(row_id) {
      },
      jsonReader: {
          repeatitems: false,
          id: "ID",
          userdata: 'rows'
      },
      viewrecords: true,
      gridComplete: function() {
      //Attach action event handlers
      $('span[name="details"]').click(function() {
      var row_id = this.id;
      var data = $("#transactionList").getGridParam('userData');
      var rowData;

      $.each(data, function(index,el){
        if(el.ID==row_id)
            rowData = el;
        });

      var message = '<div class="sectionItem"><span class="label">Asset Name:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><span class="value">'+rowData.assname+rowData.assname2+'</span></div>';
      message += '<div class="sectionItem"><span class="label">Amount:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><span class="value">'+rowData.net_proc+'</span></div>';
      message += '<div class="sectionItem"><span class="label">Transaction Date:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><span class="value">'+rowData.tran_date+'</span></div>';
      $.popMessage('Transactions Details', message);
      }).addToolTip('Details');
    }
})
    $("#transactionList").setGridParam({datatype: 'json'}).trigger("reloadGrid");
;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exact origin of the problem is not clear from the code which you posted. You use `sortname: 'tran_date', sortorder: 'desc'` in the code posted, but the `colModel` has no column with the name `'tran_date'`.

In general it's important to understand, that the server code `url: "/cc/transaction/show/"+accountId` have to return **sorted** data. The options `sortname: 'tran_date', sortorder: 'desc'` will be used to build the values of `sidx` and `sord` parameters which will be send to the server. So the server have to return the data sorted by `sidx` unsing `sord` order. I suppose that your current server code don't do this.

**UPDATE**: The server *should* returns sorted data. If it's *really* impossible you have to resort the data directly after the first loading. To do this you can test inside of `loadComplete` callback whether you are loading the data *at the first time*. On the first loading the value of `datatype` is the original value `"json"` or `"xml"` depend on the format of the data returned from the server. Later `datatype` will be changed to `"local"`. So if the value of `datatype` option is not `"local"` you can trigger `"reloadGrid"`. The corresponding code could looks like below

```js
$("#transactionList").jqGrid({
    url: "/cc/transaction/show/" + accountId,
    datatype: "json",
    rowNum: 1, // initial small value
    loadonce: true,
    loadComplete: function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        if ($this.jqGrid("getGridParam", "datatype") !== "local") {
            setTimeout(function () {
                $this.jqGrid("setGridParam", { rowNum: 20 }); // the real value
                $this.trigger("reloadGrid");
            }, 50);
        }
    },
    ... // other options which you need
});
```

Comment: Oleg, thanks for quick response.  I have tran_date in there, just bad formatting.  Also, if I don't include URL, no data appears.  I can't sort server side(long story).

Comment: @shef: The server *should* returns sorted data. If it is really impossible you have to resort the data directly after the first loading. I'll append my answer with the corresponding code example.

Comment: Thank you so much, that works perfectly.  The system I am locked into doesn't allow me to do an "order by" or "sort by" on the db, as crazy as that sounds.  Should I assume pagination won't work with this configuration?  thanks again

Comment: @shef: You are welcome! The pagination do work because it will be implemented *locally* by jqGrid. So you should just set the value of `rowNum` which you need. If you don't need local pagination you can set `rowNum` to some large value like `rowNum: 1000`.