# jqGrid reload server

Tags: jqgrid, refresh, restore

I have a table filled with data that I want to sort and filter.

I implemented an auto-refresh function, which loads data from the server each time, but I want to restore sort and filter options, which I can do.

I use `trigger("reloadGrid",[{current:true}])`, setting the datatype to json so that the data are retrieved from the server, in the `autorefresh` function, and the sort and filter options are used in the `loadcomplete` method with a `setTimeout`, as explained in other stackoverflow questions.

That works, but each time the grid refreshes, I see during one second the grid with the full data, not sorted nor filtered, and then the data are locally sorted/filtered.

Given that I want an 5 seconds auto-refresh, is there a way I can prevent the `reloadGrid` method from displaying the full data when there is a server request but wait for the `reload` in `loadComplete` to refresh the display?

Reload used in the `autorefresh` function :

```
$("#MyGrid").jqGrid("setGridParam",{url:"list.php", datatype:"json"}).trigger("reloadGrid",[{current:true}]);
```

Model :

```
jQuery("#MyGrid").jqGrid({
  url:'list.php',  
  datatype: "json",
  loadonce:true,
  ...
  loadComplete: function(){
    if ($("#MyGrid").jqGrid("getGridParam", "datatype") !== "local") {
      setTimeout(function () {
        $("#MyGrid").jqGrid("setGridParam",{search:srch,postData:post});
      })
    };
  }
```

Comment: Why are using `setTimeout` inside `loadComplete`? Can you link to the question where you got that idea?

Comment: Hi ! The question where I got this idea can be found here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/14468880/2136486. If I'm not wrong, by doing this, the reload inside loadcomplete is waiting that data from server are correctly retrieved. Am I correct ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use setInterval JavaScript function to do automatic refreshing

```
var grid = $("#list"),
intervalId = setInterval(
    function() {
        grid.trigger("reloadGrid",[{current:true}]);
    },
    60000); // Every 1 min
```

to stop the grid reload you can use one more JavaScript function:

```
clearInterval(intervalId);
```

In the "reloadGrid" I use less known parameter current:true which is described here to preserve the current selection in the grid.

You can see the [Reload Jqgrid by given interval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5297007/reload-jqgrid-by-given-interval)