# jqGrid unable to set filter value in first charge

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I know there are many questions related to this topic. I have read them, I followed the indications and I still can not make my code work.

I have a grid with a filtertoolbar. Clicking on an element of the grid opens a page. My goal is that when I return to the grid again, the filters that were applied will be kept.

To save the filters I use a session variable (in another question it is recommended to use something else, but for now I want it to work as well)

```
jQuery("#tbl").jqGrid('filterToolbar',{stringResult:true, searchOnEnter:false, defaultSearch:'cn',
        afterSearch:function(){
            var filters = JSON.parse($("#tbl").getGridParam('postData').filters);
            var rules = filters.rules;
            sessionStorage.setItem("Filters1",JSON.stringify(rules));}});
```

To restore filters I use the following function. I know that this function works correctly if I assign it to a click event of any button, however I do not know where to call it to run when loading the page.

```
function Filters(){
  var searchFiler = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("Filters1"));   
  var  grid = $("#tbl"), f;
  if (searchFiler.length === 0) {
        grid[0].p.search = false;
        $.extend(grid[0].p.postData,{filters:""});
    }
    f = {groupOp:"AND",rules:[]};
    f.rules = searchFiler;
    grid[0].p.search = true;
    $.extend(grid[0].p.postData,{filters:JSON.stringify(f)});
    grid.trigger("reloadGrid",[{page:1,current:true}]);
}
```

Finally, I charge the grid as follow:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function CargaGRID(){
        jQuery("#tbl").jqGrid("GridUnload"); 

        jQuery("#tbl").jqGrid({ 
            url:'inc/arts.json.php?Id=' + $("#Id").val(), 
            datatype: "json",   
            colNames:['IdArt, 'CRC'],
            colModel:[{name:'IdArt',index:'IdArt', hidden:true},   
                    {name:'CRC',index:'CRC', hidden:true} 
                    ],      
            rowNum:100, 
            rowTotal: 2000,
            rowList:[],
            loadonce:true, 
            mtype: "POST", 
            gridview: true,
            pager: '#pager', 
            sortname: 'IdArt', 
            viewrecords: true, 
            sortorder: "asc", 
            caption:"",
            ignoreCase:true,
            width:980,
            shrinkToFit:false,
            height:h,
            loadComplete:function(){
                $("tr.jqgrow:odd").css("background", "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.03)");
        },
            ondblClickRow:function(rowid){$("#btnEdit").click();}
        });

        jQuery("#tbl").jqGrid('navGrid','#pager',{edit:false,add:false,del:false,search:false,refresh:false});              
        jQuery("#tbl").jqGrid('filterToolbar',{stringResult:true, searchOnEnter:false, defaultSearch:'cn',
            afterSearch:function(){
                var filters = JSON.parse($("#tbl").getGridParam('postData').filters);
                var rules = filters.rules;
                sessionStorage.setItem("filtrosArticulos",JSON.stringify(rules));

        }});

        $("a.ui-jqgrid-titlebar-close.HeaderButton").hide()     

    }
```

What do I have to do or where do I have to call the function to load the grid with the filters applied?

**UPDATE**

I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14467883/jqgrid-retain-filter-on-reload)