# sort jqgrid on first column

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

I am trying to sort a jqgrid onload here is the grid's code.

```
    url:"",
    datatype: 'json',
    colNames:['col1', 'col2'],
    colModel:[{name:'col1',index:'col1', search:false, sortable:true},{name:'col2',index:'col2', search:false, sortable:true} ],
    paging:true,
    pager: $("#page"),
    loadonce:true,
    sortable:true,
    caption: 'my table',
    shrinkToFit:shrinkToFit,
    forcefit:true,
    viewrecords: true,
    sortname:'col1',
    sortorder:'desc',
    autowidth:true, 
    multiselect: true,
    autoheight:true
```

But its not getting sorted. I wanted to sort the grid on first column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general **the server** is responsible for sorting of the data at the first load. I think that it's not always possible if one have to work with *existing* backend so I posted [the feature request](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/feature-request/local-sorting-at-least-optional-of-the-data-loaded-with-loadoncetrue/#p28347). Unfortunately, the the feature request was not implemented. So you the choice between modification your server code so that it do sort initial data on the server side or to use some small workaround where one force *local* reloading of the grid after the first load. There are many old answers which provide how one can implement this. [The answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8119695/315935), [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16648070/315935) or [one more answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13679698/315935) show almost the same technique. The last from tree above answers suggest to use `rowNum: 1` at the first load and change it to the value which you really need (like `rowNum: 20`) after the first load. It's small optimization which improves the performance.